# Using MediaRecorder and MediaStream with Next.JS

Tags: next.js, next.js13, mediastream, web-mediarecorder

This is one problem I am facing while developing an small web app with Next.JS.

The app allows the user to record his own voice and then play it back. Although it works up to a point, it has a serious issue. At this stage I can do the audio recording as well as play the audio back once. But it starts getting into trouble if I want to play back multiple times. I am likely making some basic mistake in my code, but have no idea where. If somebody sees something missing please let me know.

This is the kind of error message I get, when trying to play more than once:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error (Uncaught (in promise))
AbortError(DOMException): 
    The fetching process for the media resource was aborted by the user agent at the user's request.
```

Now, below is the complete code for the Next.JS component:

```
'use client'

import {useState,useRef} from "react";


const AudioRecorderPlayer = () => {
  const [permission, setPermission] = useState(false);
  const [stream, setStream] = useState<MediaStream>();
  const [recordingStatus, setRecordingStatus] = useState("inactive");
  const mrRef = useRef<MediaRecorder | null>(null);
  const audioChunksRef = useRef<Blob[]>([]);
  const [audio, setAudio] = useState('');
  const dataType = "video/webm";


  const getMicrophonePermission = async () => {
    if ("MediaRecorder" in window) {
      try {
        const streamData = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio: true,
            video: false,
        });
        setPermission(true);
        setStream(streamData);
      } catch (err) {
        alert("err.message");
      }
    } else {
      alert("The MediaRecorder API is not supported in your browser.");
    }
  }; /* End of getMicrophonePermission */


  const startRecording = async () => {
        mrRef.current = null
        audioChunksRef.current = []

        setRecordingStatus("recording");
        const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream!, {
            mimeType: dataType,
            audioBitsPerSecond: 16*44100
        });
        mrRef.current = mediaRecorder;

        let localAudioChunks = [];//[Blob];
        mediaRecorder.start()
        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
            if (typeof event.data === "undefined") return;
            if (event.data.size === 0) return;
            localAudioChunks.push(event.data);
            audioChunksRef.current.push(event.data);
        };
    }; /* End of startRecording */


    const stopRecording = () => {
        setRecordingStatus("inactive");
        if (!mrRef.current) return
        mrRef.current?.stop();
        mrRef.current.onstop = async () => {
            console.log("Here dataType = ",dataType)
            const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunksRef.current, {
                                                                 type: dataType});
            const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
            setAudio(audioUrl);
        };
    }; /* End of stopRecording */


  return (
    <div>
      <main>
                {!permission ? (
                    <button onClick={getMicrophonePermission} type="button">
                        Get Microphone
                    </button>
                ): null}
                {permission && recordingStatus === "inactive" ? (
          <button onClick={startRecording} type="button">
            Start Recording
                    </button>
                ) : null}
                {recordingStatus === "recording" ? (
            <button onClick={stopRecording} type="button">
                        Stop Recording
                    </button>
                ) : null}
        <audio src={audio} id="audio-player" controls />
      </main>
    </div>
  );

}; /* End of AudioRecorderPlayer */

export default AudioRecorderPlayer;
```

If more detailed information is needed, let me know in the comments.

Comment: Do you found the solution? I have exact problem but only on ios 16.x. Also my app not throwing any exception

Comment: It's a while ago. I think I did not properly solved the problem. and I only got it to work more on some browsers less on others. I did not try on iOS. If you know how to make it work on Firefox I'd still be interested.